# Calculating formula equation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

the current code takes in a formula and performs the calculation. I am finding the position of the 1st operator and working out the number to the left and right -

```
 //array of characters
            char[] arrayOfOperators = {'/', '*', '+', '/'};
            string input = "5+4+6+1";

               foreach (int i in input)  
               {

                while (arrayOfOperators.Any(input.Contains))
               {


                 int sign = input.IndexOf(  ); //current operator ()
                 Console.WriteLine(sign);

                 string beforeOperator = input.Substring(0, sign);
                 string afterOperator = input.Substring(sign + 1); 

                 // populate these two variables
                 int previousOperatorPosition = (beforeOperator.LastIndexOf('+'));   //   instead of +??      
                 int nextOperatorPosition = (afterOperator.IndexOf('+'));     //   instead of +??  

                 //parse and store in a variable
                 int leftNumber = int.Parse(beforeOperator.Substring(previousOperatorPosition + 1));
                 int rightNumber = 0;

                 if (nextOperatorPosition != -1) 
                 {
                   rightNumber = int.Parse(afterOperator.Substring(0, nextOperatorPosition));    
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    rightNumber = int.Parse(afterOperator);
                 }          
                 // Do calculation with 2 previous variables, and store result in variable
                 int result = (leftNumber + rightNumber);
                 input = (beforeOperator.Substring(0, previousOperatorPosition + 1) + result +  (afterOperator.Substring(1)));
```

I am trying to get the current operator - `int sign = input.IndexOf(  );` Im not sure what I should have in the brackets

As well as here -

```
int previousOperatorPosition = (beforeOperator.LastIndexOf('+'));   //   instead of +??      
int nextOperatorPosition = (afterOperator.IndexOf('+'));     //   instead of +??
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: I really recommend you to use something like https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/. It's more robust, easy to use and after all you won't get headache by parsing strings and try to evaluate them... Try also to read more about ANTLR, Roslyn or something alike...

Comment: Its a lot easier to convert the expression from infix to postfix and then just pop operators off a stack. See http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/